# Efetuar UPDATE com valores de outra tabela, em colunas com mesmo nome

Tags: sql-server

Possuo as seguintes tabelas *tabela_A* e *tabela_B*, essas tabelas possuem cerca de 20 colunas idênticas. O que preciso fazer é atualizar os valores da tabela_B a partidar da tabela_A, onde as colunas sejam as mesmas.

Há uma forma de automatizar o processo de UPDATE sem ter que referenciar as colunas uma por uma através de um JOIN?

Comment: As colunas são idênticas e estão na mesma ordem?

Comment: Sim, @AndrewPaes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma um script para gerar o update e depois fazer a execução dinâmica.

Criando a estrutura da base:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Id] int, [name] varchar(50));

CREATE TABLE Table2
    ([Id] int, [name] varchar(50));

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Id], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 'C3PO'),
    (2, 'R2D2'),
    (3, 'BB8');

INSERT INTO Table2
    ([Id], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 'Luke'),
    (2, 'Darth');
```

Criando o script que irá gerar o UPDATE executar o mesmo:

```
declare @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @name VARCHAR(50)

set @query = 'update table2 set '

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
select name from syscolumns
where [id] = (select [id] from sysobjects where name = 'Table1') -- Busca o objeto da tabela referência

OPEN cursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    set @query = @query + 'Table2.' + @name + ' = Table1.' +@name + ',' 

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @name
END

set @query = substring(@query, 1, (len(@query) - 1)) + ' from Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id'

print @query; -- Verifica a query gerada

execute sp_executesql @query; -- Executa a query

CLOSE cursor1;
DEALLOCATE cursor1;
```

Comment: Fazendo algumas alterações mas a dica do uso de `CURSOR` já adiantou bastante.

Answer (score 4):

Tente o seguinte:

```
UPDATE
    Table_B
SET
    Table_B.col1 = Table_A.col1,
    Table_B.col2 = Table_A.col2
FROM
    Table_A
INNER JOIN
    Table_B
ON
    Table_A.id = Table_B.id
```

Retirado de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server

Comment: Obrigado, Thomas. Mas desta forma eu preciso citar todos as 20(ou mais) colunas a serem atualizadas, e estou tentando buscar uma forma de não precisar disso.

Comment: "..sem ter que referenciar as colunas uma por uma através de um JOIN?" - A questão solicita fazer o update sem citar as colunas.

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode atualizar várias tabelas em uma mesma query, no entanto, você pode usar uma `transaction` para certificar-se de que as duas querys de `UPDATE` são tratadas:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE Table1
  SET Table1.LastName = 'DR. XXXXXX' 
FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2
WHERE T1.id = T2.id
and T1.id = '011008';

UPDATE Table2
SET Table2.WAprrs = 'start,stop'
FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2
WHERE T1.id = T2.id
and T1.id = '011008';

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Obrigado, Bruno. Mas eu quero atualizar somente a tabela_B, com valores advindos da tabela_A.